# If anything, what can cause a rocket engine to flame out prematurely?

Tags: rockets, engine-design, liquid-fuel

I would assume that dropping flow rates or a drop in chamber pressure would cause the engine to stop thrusting, but I am unaware as to what specifically these conditions might be.

Comment: if the exhaust flow fails to reach the speed of sound in the engine throat then it will slow, instead of speed up as it exits the nozzle, resulting in a loss of thrust.

Comment: Another condition would be if external pressure is higher than chamber pressure such as deep underwater or in a high pressure environment such as on a gas giant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When thinking about what *could* happen, a fruitful method of approach can be considering what *has* happened.

[This chart](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20120001539.pdf) from the early days of SSME testing shows some of the ways things can go wrong.

- Turbopump failures resulting in loss of flow and Other Bad Things
- Burn-throughs of combustion machinery
- Ruptures of piping
- Valve    failures

[image]